# Search Mysql with LIKE%% for two last different value

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

I have a mysql database with some records. I want to have the last two records from this kind:

Note: the id field is auto increment, but my records may not follow each other. It looks like this:

```
ID MYVALUE
1  42-K0000001
2  42-K0000002
3  42-B0000001
4  42-B0000002
```

And I want to have the last record of 42-KXXXXXXX and 42-BXXXXXX to pass it to a php variable.

I tried this:

```
mysql_query("SELECT myvalue from mydatabase WHERE myvalue LIKE %42-K% and myvalue LIKE %42-B% ORDER BY id DESC");
```

Will this work:

```
 SELECT myvalue 
    FROM mydatabase 
    WHERE myvalue LIKE "k%" 
    ORDER BY id DESC 
    LIMIT x
UNION
SELECT myvalue 
    FROM mydatabase 
    WHERE myvalue 
    LIKE "b%" 
    ORDER BY id DESC 
    LIMIT x
```

Comment: 1. do not use "AND" between likes. I think you should use UNION to get last 42-KX and 42KB

Comment: And what if there is only a 42-KX? How to get them into php variable to check if they exists or not?

Comment: try this:
$kx = $kb = null;
$result = mysql_query($YourSqlHere);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 if(substr($row['myvalue'], 0, 5) == '42-KX')
  $kx = $row['myvalue'];
 else
  $kb = $row['myvalue'];
}

Answer (score 2):

you have to use OR not AND like this

```
SELECT * myvalue from mydatabase WHERE myvalue LIKE '42-K%' OR myvalue LIKE '42-B%' ORDER BY id DESC
```

or with MID and IN LIKE THIS

```
SELECT *
FROM x
WHERE MID(myvalue, 4, 1) IN ('K', 'B')
ORDER BY id DESC
```

`MID(myvalue, 4, 1)` create a substring of your `myvalue` field from position 4, with 1 character!

its easer to read and better to expand

Comment: You don't need the leading `%`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `AND` by a `OR` :

```
SELECT * myvalue 
FROM mydatabase 
WHERE myvalue LIKE %42-K% 
    OR myvalue LIKE %42-B% 
ORDER BY id DESC
```